# Type.CHECKBOX not being clicked when using formatter

Tags: next.js, bootstrap-table

I am using react-bootstrap-table2-editor in my next.js project.

I have this:

```
     const columns = [
    ...
    {
    dataField: 'isActive',
    sort: true,
    text: 'Status',

    formatter: (cell, row) => {
   //     console.log(cell, row)
        return (
            <span>
                <Input type="checkbox" style={{ marginLeft: 90 }} checked={cell} onClick={() => saveChange(row)} ></Input>
            </span>
        );
    },
},]

     async function saveChange(row) {

    .... making api call to save isActive status 

}
```

When I click on this checkbox fields it wont changes its value and behave like its readonly. 
saveChanges function is being called and api call works fine here just checkbox not changing values on checking / uncheckin.

Basically I want to make an api call to save as soon as I check / uncheck this checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
 {
                dataField: 'isActive',
                sort: true,
                text: 'Status',
                 editor: {
                        type: Type.CHECKBOX,
                        value: 'Y:N'
                    },
                formatter: (cell, row, rowIndex) => {
                    //     console.log(cell, row)
                    return (
                        <Input type="checkbox" style={{ marginLeft: 90 }} checked={cell} ></Input>
                    );
                },
            },

    <BootstrapTable
                                            striped
                                            hover
                                            condensed
                                            pagination={paginationFactory()}
                                            {...props.baseProps}
                                        cellEdit={cellEditFactory({
                                            mode: 'click', blurToSave: true,
                                            afterSaveCell: (oldValue, newValue, row, column) => { saveChange(row) }
                                        })}
```